# Information about currently executing request in corba

Tags: corba

I need information about currently executing request in server in CORBA application. I am using Corba omniORB. I know, that in Ice for every function implemented in server-side there is parameter Ice::Current. Is there something similar in CORBA ?

Comment: What information do you need about the request? CORBA has a Current object but it doesn't offer that much.

Comment: I am using SSL, so I need information about client certificate in server-side.

Comment: How I can get access to Corba current object ? In object skeleton code, generated from IDL there is no such parameter

Answer (score 0):

Client certificates and other transport-related details were deliberately abstracted away by the CORBA spec. OmniORB might have some extension that allows this kind of investigation but I doubt it.

Your best bet is to turn up logging to the max and see if the client certificate's details appear anywhere.